# I cant place my new middleware where I want to place it in the rack stack

Tags: ruby-on-rails, middleware, omniauth, rack, omniauth-google-oauth2

I wrote a new middleware called `RescueAuthTokenFromOmniauth`, which rescues an exception created by either `OmniAuth::Strategies::GoogleOauth2` or `OmniAuth::Strategies::Facebook`. Ideally, I want to place `RescueAuthTokenFromOmniauth` just before the Omniauth middleware in the stack.

I can add `RescueAuthTokenFromOmniauth` to the stack by using

```
# application.rb
config.middleware.use RescueAuthTokenFromOmniauth
```

But when I try to do, for example,

```
# application.rb
config.middleware.insert_before(OmniAuth::Strategies::GoogleOauth2, RescueAuthTokenFromOmniauth)
```

I get the following error when running `rails middleware`:

```
No such middleware to insert before: OmniAuth::Strategies::GoogleOauth2
```

The `Omniauth::Strategies` middleware was added by the gems [omniauth-google-oauth2](https://github.com/zquestz/omniauth-google-oauth2) and [omniauth-facebook](https://github.com/simi/omniauth-facebook).

Is there a way to reference `OmniAuth::Strategies::GoogleOauth2` in `application.rb` so that I can place my new middleware just before it?

I'm using rails (6.0.3.6).

Here's the result of running rails middleware. It already includes `RescueAuthTokenFromOmniauth` by using `config.middleware.use RescueAuthTokenFromOmniauth`

```
use Webpacker::DevServerProxy
use ActionDispatch::HostAuthorization
use Rack::Sendfile
use ActionDispatch::Static
use ActionDispatch::Executor
use Rack::Rewrite
use ActiveSupport::Cache::Strategy::LocalCache::Middleware
use Rack::Runtime
use Rack::MethodOverride
use ActionDispatch::RequestId
use RequestStore::Middleware
use ActionDispatch::RemoteIp
use Sprockets::Rails::QuietAssets
use Rails::Rack::Logger
use ActionDispatch::ShowExceptions
use WebConsole::Middleware
use ActionDispatch::DebugExceptions
use BetterErrors::Middleware
use Rollbar::Middleware::Rails::RollbarMiddleware
use ActionDispatch::ActionableExceptions
use ActionDispatch::Reloader
use ActionDispatch::Callbacks
use ActiveRecord::Migration::CheckPending
use ActionDispatch::Cookies
use ActionDispatch::Session::CookieStore
use ActionDispatch::Flash
use ActionDispatch::ContentSecurityPolicy::Middleware
use Rack::Head
use Rack::ConditionalGet
use Rack::ETag
use Rack::TempfileReaper
use Warden::Manager
use RescueAuthTokenFromOmniauth
use Rack::Attack
use Bullet::Rack
use OmniAuth::Strategies::GoogleOauth2
use OmniAuth::Strategies::Facebook
run SaverLife::Application.routes
```

These are all the settings regarding middleware in `application.rb`

```
require_relative '../lib/rescue_auth_token_from_omniauth'
...
config.middleware.use RescueAuthTokenFromOmniauth
```

My new middleware defined in `lib/rescue_auth_token_from_omniauth.rb`

```
class RescueAuthTokenFromOmniauth
  def initialize(app)
    @app = app
  end

  def call(env)
    begin
      @app.call env
    rescue ActionController::InvalidAuthenticityToken
      [302, {'Location' => "/users/sign_up", 'Content-Type' => 'text/html'}, ['Invalid Authenticity Token']]
    end
  end
end
```

I add OmniAuth middleware inside `devise.rb`

```
  # ==> OmniAuth
  # Add a new OmniAuth provider. Check the wiki for more information on setting
  # up on your models and hooks.
  # config.omniauth :github, 'APP_ID', 'APP_SECRET', scope: 'user,public_repo'
  config.omniauth :google_oauth2,
    Rails.application.credentials.dig(Rails.env.to_sym, :google_client_id),
    Rails.application.credentials.dig(Rails.env.to_sym, :google_client_secret)

  config.omniauth :facebook,
    Rails.application.credentials.dig(Rails.env.to_sym, :facebook_key),
    Rails.application.credentials.dig(Rails.env.to_sym, :facebook_secret),
    scope: "email", info_fields: 'name,email,first_name,last_name'
```

This is how my OmniAuth initializer looks like

```
# omniauth.rb
OmniAuth.config.logger = Rails.logger

OmniAuth.config.allowed_request_methods = [:post]
```

Note: I know right now `RescueAuthTokenFromOmniauth` is before the `Omniauth::Strategies` middleware, so my feature works. But I want to explicitly set it with `insert_before` so that it's clear that it should go before the `Omniauth::Strategies` middleware.

Answer (score 0):

you can do that when omniauth initialize

```rb
# config/initializers/omniauth.rb
require Rails.root.join("lib/rescue_auth_token_from_omniauth")

Rails.application.config.middleware.use OmniAuth::Builder do
  provider :google_oauth2, ENV['GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID'], ENV['GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET']
end

Rails.application.config.middleware.insert_before(OmniAuth::Builder, RescueAuthTokenFromOmniauth)
```

**note** that if use above code, you should not add your middleware on application.rb otherwise it'll duplicate.

Comment: What if I set up the middleware in devise.rb by using `config.omniauth` like in [here](https://github.com/heartcombo/devise/wiki/OmniAuth:-Overview#before-you-start)?

I tried using `Rails.application.config.middleware.insert_before(OmniAuth::Builder, RescueAuthTokenFromOmniauth)` and `Rails.application.config.middleware.insert_before(OmniAuth::Strategies::GoogleOauth2, RescueAuthTokenFromOmniauth)` below `config.omniauth` but I got the same error message.

Comment: you can rename `01_omniauth.rb` in order to the `OmniAuth` middleware be inited first before file `devise` be executed. @LuisCésar, i just tested and it worked.

Comment: That didn't work for me. I added how I have set up omniauth.rb and devise.rb to the original post.

Comment: try `Rails.application.config.middleware.insert_before(OmniAuth::Strategies::GoogleOauth2, RescueAuthTokenFromOmniauth)` on `omniauth.rb` since this file be executed after `devise.rb` @LuisCésar

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Lam Phan's approach. If you did want to keep the initializer in a separate initializer file, make sure to reference the dependency initializers with something like `require_relative './omniauth.rb'`, otherwise it will be sensitive to the alphabetical ordering of the filenames.

Comment: What if I set up the middleware in devise.rb by using `config.omniauth` like in [here](https://github.com/heartcombo/devise/wiki/OmniAuth:-Overview#before-you-start)?

I tried using `Rails.application.config.middleware.insert_before(OmniAuth::Builder, RescueAuthTokenFromOmniauth)` and `Rails.application.config.middleware.insert_before(OmniAuth::Strategies::GoogleOauth2, RescueAuthTokenFromOmniauth)` below `config.omniauth` but I got the same error message.

Comment: Did you move the initialization from `application.rb` to `config/initializers/`?  If so, you may still need to add `require_relative './devise.rb'` at the top of your initializer.